# How to display minimap in Sublime Text with distraction free mode?

Tags: sublimetext3

I don't see an option in the settings to keep the right hand "minimap" during sublime text's distraction free mode (`shift+f11`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter distraction free mode with (`shift+11`) and them go to your menu using `alt` and in the menu section that says `View` click there and select `Show minimap`

Hope helps :)